# Transformar linha em coluna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Boa noite,
Estou com um problema de juntas mais de 500 arquivos csv, onde preciso de um dado muito importante que esta em uma linha (A8), porem ela precisa virar coluna(como esta na segunda imagem), estou tentando usar a função iloc, porem não esta dando certo, para juntar todas as planilhas estou usando esse código, mais antes preciso que o dataframe fique como na segunda foto, desde ja agradeço pela ajuda de todos e pelas sugestões:

```
path = r'C:/PJS_PY/HMR_DTS/DTS_BSE'

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', skiprows=range(0,8))
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu sugeriria mudar um pouco o título da pergunta já que, da forma como está, sugere que seu problema é muito mais geral do que realmente é. A propósito, caso alguém venha aqui para saber como se transpõe um pandas dataframe, basta fazer `df.T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução é abrir o arquivo novamente e selecionar apenas a informação que você quer. Com essa informação, você cria uma nova coluna.

Como você não apresentou um exemplo replicável, criei uma base de dados fictícia que replica seu problema. Assim, suponha que temos um arquivo em csv com essa cara:

```
k,19090
med,35000
gui, 23199
jkjd, 98082
jksjkjs, 890001
jksjkjs, 890001
gui, 23199
medidor, 18900005
name, idade, cor, sexo, income
Maria, 29, white, woman, 3000
João, 32, black, man, 2500
```

Uma implementação dessa solução que sugeri, seria:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

all_files= ["data.csv"]
li=[]

for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', skiprows=range(0,8))
        f = open(filename, "r")
        for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            # pega especificamente a informação da linha 8:
            if index==7:
                # Como você quer só os números, 
                # aplique um regex para pegar só o código numérico
                numbers = re.findall(r"[\d+]", line)
                medidor_number = ''.join(numbers)
                medidor_var = [medidor_number]*len(df)
                df = pd.DataFrame({"Medidor": medidor_var}).join(df)
                #no seu caso, que tem vários arquivos,
                #faça o apensamento apenas aqui
                #li.append(df)
        f.close()

print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
    Medidor name, idade, cor, sexo, income
0  18900005  Maria, 29, white, woman, 3000
1  18900005     João, 32, black, man, 2500
```

Comment: Boa tarde!
Maravilha Lucas, é isso mesmo porem na realidade eu precisaria pegar toda a informação contida apôs "Medidor (Serial): ", qual seria a alteração no script para isso?

Comment: remove o regex. Tira `re.findall(r"[\d+]", line)` e coloca `line`